# How to make sea races appear in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm nearing 100% completion and have only the sea races to complete (with the 1 motorcycle race). I've completed the mission "Hood Safari" and have tried hopping on the in-game version of the jet ski (as Franklin) to see if that helps, but they still don't show.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see Speedophile races, you need to be on a Speedophile Seashark jet ski and you need to have finished "Hood Safari."  In order to participate in Street Races, you must have finished the Strangers and Freaks mission, "Shift Work," and you need to be playing as Franklin.

Looks like you've done that. A similar question was posted to the [Rockstar Support](http://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/200345896-Sea-Races-or-Street-Races-not-appearing-in-GTA-V), here is Rockstar Games reply:

> We are looking into a few reports about this now.  If you would like
>   to receive an email notification as soon as there is more information
>   about a potential fix, please log into the Support Site and click
>   Subscribe at the top of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Look on the map for Strangers and Freaks between the hours of 20:00 - 5:00 for "Shift Work."

I had this issue too. The first time I encountered "Shift Work" I got a crappy car and after several tries I gave up. I upgraded Franklin's car and tried to come back to start the quest but looked everywhere and couldn't find him again. The mission ? was not showing up on the map. I was actually reading this site and the original posting on Rockstar's page when I happened to look at the map and see the mission pop up! I cleared the race and opened up street race events. Then I realized that it was roughly midnight in-game. The help text informed me that races are only available during 20:00 - 5:00. I wonder if this isn't a bug but rather you just need to look for this mission during these hours.